# Jest test fails at very first import statement (unexpected identifier) in create-react-native-app project

Tags: jestjs, create-react-native-app

New to using jest and running into immediate test failure on an existing `create-react-native-app` project when trying to run `npm test` even though the code appears to work fine when run in the android studio AVD. Error in question looks like

```
➜ npm test

> spicex_react_native@0.1.0 test /path/to/project
> jest

 PASS  __tests__/example-test.js
 FAIL  ./App.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /home/me/path/to/project/node_modules/tcomb-form-native/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import t from "./lib";
                                                                                                    ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

    > 1 | import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';
      2 | import React from 'react';
      3 | import { Alert, Button, ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
      4 | import Spinner from 'react-native-loading-spinner-overlay';

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:316:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (app/containers/path/to/some/component.js:1:1290)

Test Suites: 1 failed
```

Examining the component denoted by the component.js file in the android AVD, the screen renders without any errors or warnings. And the project's package.json looks like

```
{
  "name": "spicex_react_native",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.3.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-redux": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.1.0",
    "jest-expo": "~27.0.0",
    "react-native-scripts": "^1.14.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
```

Was not totally sure how could debug properly from just the docs (https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react-native.html#setup). If anyone knows what could be going on here, advice or suggestions would be appreciated.